# How do I generate a python timestamp to a particular format?

Tags: python, timestamp

In python, how would I generate a timestamp to this specific format?

2010-03-20T10:33:22-07

I've searched high and low, but I couldn't find the correct term that describes generating this specific format.

Comment: http://www.foragoodstrftime.com/

Answer (score 57, accepted):

See the following example:

```
import datetime 
now = datetime.datetime.now()
now.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') + ('-%02d' % (now.microsecond / 10000))
```

This could result in the following:
'2017-09-20T11:52:32-98'

Comment: It's also possible to use `now.isoformat()`, I find that satisfies my use case 95% of the time

Comment: Yo, the "-07" is a timezone, not the number of microseconds. Copy-paste the code in the answer and your timestamps will be off by random whole-hour multiples :-D

Answer (score 31):

You can use datetime with [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). Exemple:

```
import datetime

date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")

print(date)
```

Will print:

```
2017-09-20T12:59:43.888955
```